# What are the best practices to mirror a web app?

Tags: linux, mirroring, database-mirroring

I'm using a dedicated server which virtualize Linux machines, the data-center is located in Europe.

All the virtual machines are Linux servers, one is the Apache front-end while another is Mysql database.

Now i need to mirror this server in USA and Asia, to improve speed and allow SEO.

I thought to rsync, but i want to understand what are the best practices in order to keep all the machines updated, maintaining data integrity.

How does big companies solve the problem?

Edit (app details):
The app is a user generated content SaaS, so users continuously change the database and the filesystem. 
Let's suppose it is something similar to Google Docs, it is not possible to cache everything and deploy static clones around.

Comment: You need to be way more specific about how your app works and what exactly it does. Otherwise the only recommendation may be - use CDN instead of replicating the app.

Comment: I agree, just edit the answer

Comment: Typically with a CDN front-end as a first level approach but often eventually a lot of effort both in the application and data design and deployment. The the topic is probably too broad for ServerFault's Q&A format but try the [high scalability blog](http://highscalability.com/blog/category/example) which makes for interesting reading.

Comment: thanks for the resource, i am taking a look to the blog. I agree the topic is too broad, and that's why i need some info to restrict it.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I have to agree this is *way* too broad. But here's another thing to search for: the CAP theorem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you describe your application, I am afraid it will not be very easy to 'mirror'. Especially if the data has to change in real time (as it does with GDocs).

I am afraid MySQL is not a very good database for such deployment. Filesystem is yet another trouble.

The best thing you could do in long term, is probably redesigning the whole thing to use better tools for the job. And I would strongly suggest you hire someone who has experience with such software, to consult it for you.

You can use the CDN. CDN's are not about deploying static content everywhere. They usually rather work as a caching proxy to your servers.

If your application requests are too difficult to cache at the HTTP level, you could write your own caching server/mechanisms, which understand the inner working of your app.

Comment: I know it isn't an easy task, but i really want to know what and how to do. Consultants aren't the solution, CTO must understand the project in general. Is possible to use master-master replication in mysql. While rsync may be the solution server side.

Comment: Master-Master replication + rsync is kind of a way. But I warn you it will be MPITA to manage. I guess better than this, would be doing the replication at application level ...

Comment: Yes, Master-Master replication + rsync is the way i was thinking about. What does MPITA mean? What do you mean by doing replication at application level?

Comment: May be the use of Google DNS or Open DNS an easier solution for both DNS and SEO?

Comment: MPITA is major pain in the ass ... having just a local two server multimaster replication is not the most pleasant experience. And if things break and it gets out of sync, you can face quite some downtime. Implementing it at application level means having the server itself tell other servers about write operations ...